# In Linux shell do all commands that work in a shell script also work at the command prompt?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to interactively test code before I put it into a script and was wondering if there are any things that behave differently in a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute a script it has its own environment variables which are inherited from the parent process (the shell from which you executed the command). Only exported variables will be visible to the child script.

More information:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable
- http://www.kingcomputerservices.com/unix_101/understanding_unix_shells_and_environment_variables.htm

By the way, if you want your script to run in the same environment as the shell it is executed in, you can do it with the point command:

```
. script.sh
```

This will avoid creating a new process for you shell script.

Comment: I've never liked using the `.` shorthand - `source` does the same thing in 90% of shells and is much easier to read

Comment: I agree with you toby, I'm just stating that it is possible to use it and avoid environment variable differences :)

Answer (score 2):

A script runs in exactly the same way as if you typed the content in at a shell prompt. Even loops and if statements can be typed in at the shell prompt. The shell will keep asking for more until it has a complete statement to execute.

Comment: A script will NOT run the same way if it uses certain environment variables.

Comment: It will inherit the environment of the shell in which you are running. In your answer you mention sourcing the script, which will also inherit the environment of the shell in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

As David rightly pointed out, watch out for environment variables.

Depending on how you intend to launch your script, variables set in `.profile` and `.bashrc` may not be available. This is subject to whether the script is launched in [interactive mode](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/intandnonint.html) and whether it was a login shell. See [Quick Startup File Reference](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashbehaviour#quick_startup_file_reference).

A common problem I see is scripts that work when run from the shell but fail when run from another application (cron, nagios, buildbot, etc.) because `$PATH` was not set.

To test if a command/script would work in a *clean* session, you can login using:

```
ssh -t localhost "/bin/bash --noprofile --norc"
```

This ensures that we don't inherit any exported variables from the parent shell, and nothing from `.profile` or `.rc`.

If it works in a *clean* session and none of you're commands expect to be in [interactive mode](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/intandnonint.html), then you're good to go!

Comment: This is a typical gotcha for cron jobs: the cron environment is very minimal, and the $PATH is very likely different from your own.

Comment: @glenn So true! Will add to list above. Thanks.